# Duvida DBRef Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Possuo duas coleções no `mongodb` chamado empresas e usuários:

```
********** Coleção Empresas **********

    {
      "_id": ObjectId("54f38340448d3f436993edf6"),
      "cnpj": "12345678900000",
      "razao": "EMPRESA TESTE",
      "status": 0,
      "cidade": "ARACAJU",
      "uf": "SE",
      "usuarios": {
        "$ref": "user",
        "$id": ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772")
      }
    }

********** Coleção Usuarios **********

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),
    "cnpj" : "12345678900000",
    "usuario" : "USER 01",
    "senha" : "1234",
    "chave" : "12345",
    "status" : 0,
    "codigo" : "120",
    "tipo" : "A"
}
```

Estou com uma grande dificuldade em obter um `find` com a informação do dados da empresa juntamente com o dados do usuário pesquisado.

Sei que há uma referencia na documentação onde seria algo assim:

```
{ "$ref" : <value>, "$id" : <value>, "$db" : <value> }
```

Abaixo segue um projeção de como eu precisaria do resultado:

```
********* RESULTADO **********

 {
   "_id": ObjectId("54f38340448d3f436993edf6"),
   "cnpj": "12345678900000",
   "razao": "EMPRESA TESTE",
   "status": 0,
   "cidade": "ARACAJU",
   "uf": "SE",
   "usuarios": {
     "_id": ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),
     "cnpj": "12345678900000",
     "usuario": "USER 01",
     "senha": "1234",
     "chave": "12345",
     "status": 0,
     "codigo": "120",
     "tipo": "A"

   }
 }
```

Obrigado antecipadamente a todos que puderem ajudar.

Comment: Se estiver usando o mongoose, pode usar o populate. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 1):

O MongoDB não é capaz de montar essa estrutura nativamente. O "join" tem que ser feito manualmente por sua aplicação - essa lógica poderia ser abstraída por uma biblioteca. Ou seja, basicamente o que você pode fazer é: encontrar a empresa, extrair o ref e o id do usuário e realizar uma query pra recuperar o usuário, e finalmente combinar os resultados manualmente em um documento só.